# What Latin fonts are used in Apple's Chinese fonts?

Tags: font-identification

Many Chinese fonts seem to use other fonts for the Latin text. For e.g., Adobe Song Std uses a light version of Minion Pro. What Latin fonts are used in Apple's Chinese fonts, such as STFangsong, STKaiti, STSong, STHeiti, and STXihei? As best as I can tell, STFangsong, STKaiti, and STSong all share the same Latin font.

Answer (score 2):

*STSong, STFangsong,* and *STKaiti* use a **Garamond** clone for Latin characters. *STHeiti* uses a **Century Gothic** / **Avant Garde** clone. 
(*ST* stands for SinoType Technology Co. Ltd.)

(OS X 10.7)

Comment: Which Garamond and which Century Gothic? I found several fonts of this name from different foundries. All were very close, but all had differences in many of the letters. I need an exact match, at least for the Latin alphabet portions.

Comment: Yes, that's a general condition in the font market – there are many clones of the most classic typefaces, and they have other names. You'd be very lucky to find an exact match, but it's possible that the Chinese type foundry hasn't licensed any existing variation… However, check out this website for names of font clones/lookalikes: http://desktoppub.about.com/cs/fonts/a/lookalikefonts.htm ALSO, set some text, make a screenshot of that and feed the image into a font identification site, e.g. http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark. If the ones you mentioned are Serifs, I can imagine the others are done in Sans and in that case most likely Myriad as they do on my Mac. Here is a link that may help you break down what's going on. [Using the Chinese language on the Mac OS](http://www.yale.edu/chinesemac/pages/fonts.html)

Comment: The fonts do not seem to use Myriad.